# Ruby Gem Listen on share folder dont react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, listener

I use the gem Guard:Listen https://github.com/guard/listen, i need to listen for a share directory.

What i did: i created an windows share folder and on linux i mounted that folder to my project in lib/hl7. I see the created files on linux but the listener dont react to it. do i something wrong?

here my code:

```
listener = Listen.to('lib/hl7') do |modified,added,removed|
  puts "added absolute path array: #{added}"
end
listener.start # not blocking
```

Ty for your help

Edit1:
I just read in the listen github

> Some filesystems won't work without polling (VM/Vagrant Shared folders, NFS, Samba, sshfs, etc.).

How can i poll someting in linux?
Or does someone know anotherway to check the folder if an file was added?

Comment: You're listening to `lib/h17` which is a sub-directory of the current directory. You want `/lib/hl7`. Note the leading /.

Comment: i get then this error: /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.4.0/lib/listen/adapter/config.rb:16:in `realpath': No such file or directory @ rb_check_realpath_internal - /lib/hl7 (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: ah sry my bad, I mounted to the lib/hl7 folder, im new to linux and didnt know that /lib/hl7 is another folder. But i tried it with an regular folder and that works... but not with the mounted folder :( cant find anything in the internet to solve this